# Stanford CRF trainer in java getting stuck on large training data

Tags: classification, stanford-nlp, crf

I am using Stanford crf classifier in java. when i train the classifier on small data up to 40,000 words, it works fine, but when i increase the training data and try to train it on 170000 words, the program gets stuck only after two or three iterations.The case is same even if i provide heap space up to 4GB to the program. i am using : edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier library.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the format of your training data?  How many classes do you have?  It should be able to handle 170,000 tokens of training data.  That is close to the same size as the standard CoNLL 2003 dataset.

Comment: The sample of my training Data is :
CHAPTER O
I   O
Emma    PERS
Woodhouse   PERS
,   O
handsome    O
,   O
clever  O
,   O
and O
rich    O
,   O
with    O
a   O
comfortable O
home    O

Comment: My training data format is same as specified by Stanford . Now I have solved the problem by assigning 7g ram to my trainer program.

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on, I wouldn't think it would require 7 GB.  And 170,000 tokens is not that big at all.  Do you just have 4 tags (PERS, ORG, LOC, MISC) ?

Comment: The example data was only for showing data format
Actually i have 10 labels , I am working on eventExtraction.
and my system does not work for any thing less than 7g ram

Comment: @ShahMuzaffar Have you managed to figure out what is happening? I have the same problem with NER training. The training freezes after some iterations, even when using 30gb ram!